# Angular new router can activate to multiple views globally

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to know if there is a way to prevent multiple routes on the same time to instantiate the component if the user is not logged in.

for example:

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('MyController', ['user', '$http', MyController]);

function MyController(user, $http) {
  this.user = user;
  this.$http = $http;
}

MyController.prototype.canActivate = function() {
  return this.user.isLogin;
};
```

Here this is for this component only, there is a way to define all the routes in one place that i want this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

The most simplest way will be to create one file, for example

**protectedRoutes.js** and create this:

```
var components = [AccountController, PrivateController];

components.forEach(function(comp) {

   comp.prototype.canActivate = function() {
       return this.user.isLogin;
   }

});
```